# Laravel-4 migration help - How to get camelCase code by $table->timestamps();

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, database-migration

How to generate migrations with camelCase code?

Like If migrate users table in camelCase but "$table->timestamps()" return "created_at" & "updated_at" but I want both of them to be named "createdAt" & "updatedAt".

```
public function up()
{
   Schema::create('users', function($table){
      $table->increments('userId');
      $table->string('userName');
      $table->string('userPassword');
      $table->timestamps();
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use (add both fields manually)

```
$table->timestamp('createdAt');
$table->timestamp('updatedAt');
```

Instead of `timestamps()` and this is just a way to do the task manually while `timestamps()` do it automatically for you.

Read more on [Schema Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/schema).

Comment: Can't I use timestamps() "automated one" with camelCase? Isn't there anyway? Thanks for your kind answer.

Comment: No, that's not possible at the moment as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$table->timestamp('createdAt');
```

and

```
$table->timestamp('updatedAt');
```

to table field.

reference: http://laravel.com/docs/schema#adding-columns

Comment: Exceptions with Column not found, unknown column 'updated_at'. It's not smart enough to find those different columns when it inserts a record.

Comment: if he has used the migration $table->timestamp('updated_at'); should use {{ $user->update_at }}. But in eloquent query, you can use User::whereUpdateAt(). You can only use CamelCase eloquent.